# Model bounces in reaction to teleop_twist_keyboard input

Tags: ros-melodic, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have my robot model spawned into a gazebo world and I am attempting to drive it around using teleop.

When I push **i** to innitiate movement the robot flips up on it's rear wheels and almost flips over. Increasing the speed also creates unpredictable reactions. Stopping the robot also creates what I can only describe as a "bouncing effect". I inserted a screenshot below:

[image: image description]

The image above shows the robot flipping and bouncing after I pushed the stop (**k**) button. It's even worse when I try getting the robot to turn left or right.

I'm looking for suggestions on what could be causing this behaviour and how I can fix it, please.

**Update: **

URDF code added (with the exception of the ouster_description package lidar, inthe interest of preserving space) below as requested:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro" name="SweepBOT">

  <!-- body -->
  <xacro:property name="chasis_length" value="1.0"/>
  <xacro:property name="chasis_heigth" value="0.45"/>
  <xacro:property name="chasis_width" value="0.5"/>

  <link name="chasis">
    <inertial>
      <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
      <mass value="1.0"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.4" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.4" iyz="0.0" izz="0.2"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual name="">
      <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="${chasis_length} ${chasis_heigth} ${chasis_width}"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="">
        <color rgba="0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="${chasis_length} ${chasis_heigth} ${chasis_width}"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <gazebo reference='chasis'>
    <material>Gazebo/Orange</material>
  </gazebo>

  <!-- WHEELS -->
  <xacro:property name="wheel_radius" value="0.1"/>
  <xacro:property name="wheel_length" value="0.1"/>
  <xacro:property name="wheel_rpy" value="1.57075 0 0"/>

  <xacro:macro name="wheel" params="side position flip alt">
    <xacro:property name="wheel_xyz" value="${alt * 0.3} ${flip * 0.2} -0.25"/>

    <link name="wheel_${side}_${position}">
      <inertial>
        <mass value="1.0"/>
        <inertia ixx="1.0" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1.0" iyz="0.0" izz="1.0"/>
      </inertial>
      <visual name="">
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="${wheel_rpy}"/>
        <geometry>
          <cylinder radius="${wheel_radius}" length="${wheel_length}"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="">
          <color rgba="1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0"/>
          <texture filename=""/>
        </material>
      </visual>
      <collision>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="${wheel_rpy}"/>
        <geometry>
          <cylinder radius="${wheel_radius}" length="${wheel_length}"/>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
    </link>

    <gazebo reference='"wheel_${side}_${position}'>
      <material>Gazebo/Red</material>
    </gazebo>

    <joint name="body_wheel_${side}_${position}_joint" type="continuous">
      <parent link="chasis"/>
      <child link="wheel_${side}_${position}"/>
      <limit lower="0.0" upper="0.0" effort="0.0" velocity="0.0"/>
      <origin xyz="${alt * 0.3} ${flip * 0.2} -0.25" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
      <axis xyz="0.0 1.0 0.0"/>
    </joint>
  </xacro:macro>
  <xacro:wheel side="left" position="fore" flip='1' alt='1'/>
  <xacro:wheel side="right" position="fore" flip='-1' alt='1'/>
  <xacro:wheel side="left" position="aft" flip='1' alt='-1'/>
  <xacro:wheel side="right" position="aft" flip='-1' alt='-1'/>

  <!-- LIDAR -->
  <!-- os1_sensor_mount_joint -->
  <xacro:include filename="$(find ouster_description)/urdf/OS1-64.urdf.xacro"/>
  <OS1-64 parent="chasis" name="os1_sensor" hz="10" samples="220">
    <origin xyz="0 0 0.3" rpy="0 0 0" />
  </OS1-64>

  <!-- MULTI-CAMERA -->
  <xacro:macro name="sweeper_cams" params="">

        <gazebo reference="left_camera_frame">
            <sensor type="multicamera" name="stereo_camera">
                <update_rate>30.0</update_rate>
                <camera name="left_camera">
                    <horizontal_fov>1.3962634</horizontal_fov>
                    <image>
                        <width>800</width>
                        <height>800</height>
                        <format>R8G8B8</format>
                    </image>
                    <clip>
                        <near>0.02</near>
                        <far>300</far>
                    </clip>
                    <noise>
                        <type>gaussian</type>
                        <mean>0.0</mean>
                        <stddev>0.007</stddev>
                    </noise>
                </camera>
                <camera name="right_camera">
                    <pose>0 -0.07 0 0 0 0</pose>
                    <horizontal_fov>1.3962634</horizontal_fov>
                    <image>
                        <width>800</width>
                        <height>800</height>
                        <format>R8G8B8</format>
                    </image>
                    <clip>
                        <near>0.02</near>
                        <far>300</far>
                    </clip>
                    <noise>
                        <type>gaussian</type>
                        <mean>0.0</mean>
                        <stddev>0.007</stddev>
                    </noise>
                </camera>
                <plugin name="stereo_camera_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_multicamera.so">
                    <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
                    <updateRate>0.0</updateRate>
                    <cameraName>multisense_sl/camera</cameraName>
                    <imageTopicName>image_raw</imageTopicName>
                    <cameraInfoTopicName>camera_info</cameraInfoTopicName>
                    <frameName>right_camera</frameName>
                    <!--<rightFrameName>right_camera_optical_frame</rightFrameName>-->
                    <hackBaseline>0.07</hackBaseline>
                    <distortionK1>0.0</distortionK1>
                    <distortionK2>0.0</distortionK2>
                    <distortionK3>0.0</distortionK3>
                    <distortionT1>0.0</distortionT1>
                    <distortionT2>0.0</distortionT2>
                </plugin>
            </sensor>
        </gazebo>

        <!--  -->

        <link name="left_camera">
            <inertial>
                <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
                <mass value="0.0"/>
                <inertia ixx="0.0" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.0" iyz="0.0" izz="0.0"/>
            </inertial>
            <visual name="">
                <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
                <geometry>
                    <box size="0.1 0.1 0.1"/>
                </geometry>
                <material name="">
                    <color rgba="0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0"/>
                    <texture filename=""/>
                </material>
            </visual>
            <collision>
                <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
                <geometry>
                    <box size="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
                </geometry>
            </collision>
        </link>
        <joint name="left_camera_joint" type="fixed">
            <origin xyz="0.45 -${chasis_width / 1.82} 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
            <parent link="chasis"/>
            <child link="left_camera"/>
        </joint>

        <link name="right_camera">
            <inertial>
                <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
                <mass value="0.0"/>
                <inertia ixx="0.0" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.0" iyz="0.0" izz="0.0"/>
            </inertial>
            <visual name="">
                <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
                <geometry>
                    <box size="0.1 0.1 0.1"/>
                </geometry>
                <material name="">
                    <color rgba="0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0"/>
                    <texture filename=""/>
                </material>
            </visual>
            <collision>
                <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
                <geometry>
                    <box size="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
                </geometry>
            </collision>
        </link>
        <joint name="right_camera_joint" type="fixed">
            <origin xyz="0.45 ${chasis_width / 1.82} 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
            <parent link="chasis"/>
            <child link="right_camera"/>
        </joint>
        
    </xacro:macro>
  <xacro:sweeper_cams/>

</robot>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/368096/model-bounces-in-reaction-to-teleop_twist_keyboard-input/) by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 247 on 2020-12-18

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) on 2020-12-21**:
Are the wheels spinning the way you expect for forward, backward, and turning motions?  You may check by making your robot "float" with a fixed joint between `world` and `base_link`, so physics doesn't get in the way as suggested in [this Gazebo answer](https://answers.gazebosim.org//question/21826/how-to-use-the-gazebo_ros-skid-steer-drive-plugin/).  If that works, then the issue may be your physical parameters (inertia, friction, etc.).  Either way, you should post your URDF file(s) for further troubleshooting.

**Comment by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) on 2020-12-21**:
@Tryan: Hello again :-)

I added my urdf code as you requested.

Regarding the spinning movements of the wheels, I am certain they are moving in the right and required directions. I can get the model to move without issue if I reduce the to almost zero. That is particularly important when the robot is starting from stand still. Increasing the speed tends to have the "galloping horse" effect where the robot lifts up on it's rear wheels, comes down on all four wheels and then picks up speed.

**Comment by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) on 2020-12-21**:
Haha, hi, @sisko!  I remember the tumbling wheels now :)

Looking a little closer at the URDF, it seems the wheels have significantly more inertia than the chassis (and too much for their mass value).  [The Husky's URDF](https://github.com/husky/husky/blob/melodic-devel/husky_description/urdf/wheel.urdf.xacro) provides an example of some real values `ixx="0.02467" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.04411" iyz="0" izz="0.02467"`.  You can use your mass value and the formula for a solid cylinder from [Wikipedia's List of Moments of Inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia):

```
izz = 1/2 * m * r^2
ixx = iyy = 1/12 * m * (3 * r^2 + h^2)
```

where m is the mass, r is the radius, and h is the height (wheel width).  You could also increase your chassis' mass (the [Husky's is ~46 kg](https://github.com/husky/husky/blob/melodic-devel/husky_description/urdf/husky.urdf.xacro)), and its inertia values should reflect its mass (see the formula linked above).

**Comment by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) on 2020-12-23**:
@tryan: Please excuse my ignorance because I am NOT a maths guy.
Do you take a different formular from that Wiki page depending on the shape you wish to calculate for ?
Am I correct in appling the formular you provided me to both the chassis and the wheels ?
And lastly, can you recommend a video or article to help me understand the formulae ?

**Comment by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) on 2020-12-25**:
I submitted an answer in response as it allows more characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Reposting as an answer for character limit.

Looking a little closer at the URDF, it seems the wheels have significantly more inertia than the chassis (and too much for their mass value). The Husky's URDF provides an example of some real values `ixx="0.02467" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.04411" iyz="0" izz="0.02467"`. You can use your mass value and the formula for a solid cylinder from Wikipedia's List of Moments of Inertia:

```
izz = 1/2 * m * r^2
ixx = iyy = 1/12 * m * (3 * r^2 + h^2)
```

where m is the mass, r is the radius, and h is the height (wheel width). You could also increase your chassis' mass (the Husky's is ~46 kg), and its inertia values should reflect its mass (see the formula linked above).

---

###Update

> Do you take a different formular from that Wiki page depending on the shape you wish to calculate for ? Am I correct in appling the formular you provided me to both the chassis and the wheels ?

Yes, each shape has a specific formula.  The one I posted is only for solid cylinders, like wheels, so no, you can't really use it for the chassis, too.  The values may not be extremely far off, but it's better to use the correct formula for a given shape.  Your chassis is a solid cuboid, which has

```
izz = 1/12 * m * (x^2 + y^2)
ixx = 1/12 * m * (y^2 + z^2)
iyy = 1/12 * m * (x^2 + z^2)
```

with the other values as 0.  I should have noted above that the unmentioned inertia values are 0 also.

> can you recommend a video or article to help me understand the formulae ?

[Wikipedia's Moment of Inertia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia) is as good a place to start as any for a quick overview.  Here's a [Khan Academy video lesson](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/physics/torque-angular-momentum/torque-tutorial/v/more-on-moment-of-inertia) on the topic that may be more helpful for understanding.  Also, most general physics text books cover it.

---

Originally posted by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) with karma: 1421 on 2020-12-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1